# every vertex has a degree of at least $2$ implies at least one cycle

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

I know that "conventional" proof with the longest path, but I wrote some other proof myself and would like to know if it shows exactly the same thing and could be interchangeable with the conventional one.

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a graph, in which every vertex has a degree of at least two, so $deg(u) \geqslant 2$ for every $u \in V$

in a graph of order $n$ it will be $\sum_{u \in V}{deg(u)} \ge 2n$

We also know that $2|E| = \sum_{u \in V}{deg(u)}$ satisfies for every graph.

Therefore the following must also satisfy $2|E| \ge 2n \implies |E| \ge n$

this implies that the size of the graph must be at least the order of it, which means that the number of edges must be at least the number of vertices.

by writing down all of the vertices and edges associated to two vertices at a time we get:

$V:={v_1 v_2 ... v_n}$ and  $E:={e_1 e_2 ... e_n}$ with
$$e_1 = v_1v_2$$
$$e_2=v_2v_3$$
$$e_n=v_nv_x$$

due to the fact that the graph has $n$ vertices and at least $n$ edges and the pigeonhole principle the vertex at the other end of $e_n$ has to be one of the already existing vertices in the graph but not $v_n$ itself, i.e $v_x = v_i$ with $i = 1,2,3...n-1$

this indicates that at least one cycle must exist in the graph

Comment: (Depending on how much you know about graphs) I encourage you to flesh out the final step more. It seems obvious, but how can we provide concrete details / logical steps, instead of appealing to the reader's sensibility?

Comment: @CalvinLin could it work by writing down the vertices along with their indices and associating every edge to two vertices? It seems like the pigeonhole principle could be of use

Comment: @CalvinLin could you have a quick look on the edited version?

Comment: The current setup doesn't work in my opinion. A) How are you setting up $e_1 = v_1 v_2$? Are you enforcing $ e_i = v_i v_{i+1}$ for $i = 1$ to $n-1$? If yes, how can you guarantee that? E.g. not all graphs have a Hamiltonian path B) You could  modify this idea, to show that eventually there is a cycle (not necessarily involving the nth vertex.

Comment: @CalvinLin is there another way to handle it? We did not learn hamiltonian graphs and paths and will most likely not learn it

Comment: That's what I said/meant in part B. To elaborate, 1) Set up the chain as just continuing the walk since the degree is at least 2, 2) Show that the chain can always "continue", and eventually will loop back on itself.